# in discord.py how do i make it so the bot only works in one server

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

in discord.py, how do I make it so the bot only works on one? so is there a way do this

```
x = (channel id.)

if x == (12454431344645423) #this is the channel id 
       print ('hi')
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just not add it to any other servers.  You can also just leave all the servers but one in your `on_ready` event, and then leave other servers as you join them.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
my_server = client.get_server('server id')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for server in client.servers:
        if server != my_server:
            await client.leave_server(server)

@client.event
async def on_server_join(server):
    if server != my_server:
        await client.leave_server(server)
```