# Discord Bot Leave Server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
my_server = client.get_server('server id')

@client.event

async def on_ready():

    for server in client.servers:
        if server != my_server:
            await client.leave_server(server)

@client.event

async def on_server_join(server):

    if server != my_server:
        await client.leave_server(server)
```

Finally its working if I add Server ID in ('server id') my bot leaves that server. But for some servers I don't have access so can't get the server ID.
So how do I make my bot leave that server?

Comment: Is there something wrong with your code? If so, how? Exceptions? From the look of your code (without checking) it seemed it's able to leave all servers other than `my_server`

Comment: The question [I wrote this in response to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321642/in-discord-py-how-do-i-make-it-so-the-bot-only-works-in-one-server/50321784#50321784) was on how to leave all servers but one.  You'll want to change `!=` to `==` (assuming `'server id'` is the `id` of the server you want to leave)

Comment: Hi Patrick yes that code is copied from you but actually  problem is he kicked me from server. So I don't know his server ID.
Above script leaves all server except my server or to leave only 1 server with his server ID.

I need a script like example bot should leave server if I'm not in that server. If my bot is in 20 server and I'm member of only 10 server so it should leave other 10 server.

Comment: Also i tried above code by adding to my bot.py. i changed `!=` to `==` and `'server id'` to `'845845894543'`  i tried adding both mine and other server id still nothing happened.

Comment: Is the above your full code? If so, you're missing `client.run('TOKEN')`

Comment: No its not my full code yes i hv `client.run('TOKEN')` in bottom.

do i need to use any code or just restarting bot does leave server?

Comment: Are you running this from a terminal?  Are you seeing any error message from that terminal?

Comment: i ran this bot.py file from both ssh and in cmd it works fine without error.  just i need to make leave my bot in some servers in which i don't hv access.

Comment: You have two `on_ready` events.  The second one will overwrite the first.  Merge them into a single coroutine.

Comment: Hi Patrick yes i got it done now Finally its working if i add Server ID in ('server id') my bot leaves that server. but for some servers i don't have access so can't get server ID. so how to make my bot leave that server.

Answer (score 0):

`client.leave_server(server)` takes a `Server` object.

`client.servers` returns a list of servers that the client is connected to. So your code should do what you expect.

When your bot is kicked or banned from the server, it should no longer be connected. Is this not the case?

If you're defining a method where the bot automatically leaves the server if it's anything other than your server, then is the actual problem that someone has access to your bot and is using it on their server without your permission? In that case you will need to revoke access to the bot by generating a new token, and/or changing the password to the dev console.