# How to make my bot leave others server

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I tried below code but it leaves any random 2 server if i run my bot. So if i re-run it quits 2 more random server it keeps quitting 2 server randomly if i try to re-run.
i want to make it quit only selected server so i changed `('server id')` to `('451765543236566556')` but still it quits 2 random server.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
my_server = client.get_server('server id')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for server in client.servers:
        if server != my_server:
            await client.leave_server(server)

@client.event
async def on_server_join(server):
    if server != my_server:
        await client.leave_server(server)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321642/in-discord-py-how-do-i-make-it-so-the-bot-only-works-in-one-server/50321784#50321784) leaves *every* server except for one.  Just leave the server you don't want the bot to be on.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    my_server = client.get_server('server id')
    await client.leave_server(my_server)
```